# Photoshop cc multiple layer cut

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Hi all I was just wondering if I could make a selection on multiple layers and cut or copy the selection.
I have a earth globe that I have copied 5 times and have change the designs for each. I need to break up the globe in the same areas could I break up all 5 layers at once without repeating the process 5 times ? I don't need to blend or adjust just cut or copy selected layer 
Thanks!

Comment: `Edit > Copy Merged`

Comment: That's only cutting the top layer

Comment: if the layers align in selection you can make a selection on a layer, delete the needed area then without deselecting go to another layer delete again, and so on and so forth

Comment: This isn't really what I was going for as I was looking for a more cut via layer without duplicating the main layers approach but Thank You for your help this did make things easier

Comment: Copy merged should copy *all visible data* within a selection. Then you can just paste.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question fully: copy those layers + merge them + add your selection to that 1 new layer

Perhaps a smart object will help you too